# Multiplication table in c

Tags: c

Tips on how to do multiplication table in c??

Answer (score 4):

ummm... two (nested) loops?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Really.

```
printf("2x1=2");
printf("2x2=4");
printf("2x3=6");
printf("2x4=8");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read books this is very basic things of programming you must clear this things yourself.

I personally recommend you not just to post here and get answer
Try reading  and try developing by yourself before you post it overhere.
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html

```
    int main () {
    int n = 10;
    int i, j;
    // Print row labels
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
         for (j=1; j<=n; j++) {
               //printf("\t%d",i*j);
               //Do something here to get it working.. :-)
          }
          printf("\n");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 nested loops and if you want to make it more organized, use a two-dimensional array.